# How to Run Grunt Email Builder to Process Only Specific Folder

Tags: javascript, email, gruntjs, html-email, litmus

I'm using grunt email builder combined with Pug and Watch to create my emails.

But I want to make it automatically process only the specific folder (current working folder directory) when I run grunt by default, because Grunt Email Builder is processing all files in the folder and subfolder that makes it heavier by the time.

[grunt email builder process all the folder and takes time to process when I change only one content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pid2.png)

Is there possible to do it? If yes how to do it properly?

Thanks!